# VBA: Copying Segments of data onto another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

First thing, I am a newbie with VBA please be gentle. My code is below the picture and this code has to read `Department #` and copy everything that comes under the `Department #` until the next `Department #` approaches and paste the copied data into an assigned sheet for that Departments.

In this picture, `Department 73` starts in *(A1:H1)* ends at *(A30:H30)*. The next Department start at line 31 and ends at line 37. The thing is that there are 80 departments and each of them has its own sheet. This excel files comes formatted this way. Is it possible to write a macro that can locate Departments # by reading accounts and copies three lines above it and **ONLY** its own values which are under it until it reaches the next department members 
and paste those values into an assigned sheet. Like department 3, department 5.

[image]
This code is just brainstorming, I don't exactly know how to code this...Please help if you have experience.

```
   Sub copyingdata()

   Dim sec1 As Long

   Dim Counter As Integer
   Dim MyString As String

   MyString = "Department 63"
   For i = 1 To Len(MyString)

   sec1 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Department 60", .Columns("A"), 0)
   sec1.Resize(i).Select

   Selection
   Sheets("Sheet1").Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Amanda").Range("A1")
   Sheets("Sheet1").Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Amanda").Activate
   Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End Sub
```

Comment: I have a sense of deja-vu.  I am sure I have seen that image before not long ago, but can't find the question it occurred in.

Comment: @YowE3K I know what you are talking about it was a similar pic but the question wasn't answered.

Comment: If you just wanted the contents of the "department 60" section of the source copied to a "Department 60" sheet, this wouldn't be all that difficult.  But the fact that it appears that there is no correlation between the department number and the destination sheet name is going to be problematic.

Comment: Also, how does the file **start**?  And do you need the "half" lines copied to the destination sheets, or just the "full" lines, i.e. rows 136:141 for department 60?

Comment: @YowE3K yes there is no correlation between the department number and the designated sheet and the full and half line both need to be copied under department 60 but the difficulty part is that these departments come in various length some are only 5 line and others

Comment: can be lengthy as 100 lines. So the problem was how to make the macro stop when it finished with a department and then continue on with the next department without create 80 different macros for each department and copy everything in department

Comment: I can write you some code, that's quite simple, but it would be even easier if I knew how the data looks at the start of the file.  Is there any chance you could paste in a screenshot of the first 10 lines (or to the start of the second department if that is further down than row 10)?

Comment: Yeah absolutely I will in a few hours.

Comment: @YowE3K Is there a way I chat with you privately?

Comment: @YowE3K There have some major changes, sorry if this makes it difficult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131825/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-mtbthepro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our chat, I believe the following code will split your data into the sheets you have already set up:

```
Sub AllocateDepartmentData()
    Dim prevRow As Long
    Dim deptRow As Long
    Dim deptNum As Variant
    Dim destSheet As String
    Dim destRow As Long
    prevRow = 0
    'Find the end of the first section
    deptRow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Department", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Row
    Do While deptRow > prevRow
        'Parse the cell containing the department number/name to get just the number
        deptNum = Cells(deptRow, 1).Value
        deptNum = Mid(deptNum, InStr(deptNum, " ") + 1)
        deptNum = CInt(Left(deptNum, InStr(deptNum & " ", " ") - 1))
        'Based on the department number, determine the destination sheet
        Select Case deptNum
            'One "Case" statement should be set for each destination sheet name
            Case 1, 2, 60, 61, 63
                destSheet = "Amanda"
            'Add more "Case" statements for each sheet
            Case 73, 74
                destSheet = "Shannon"
            'And finally catch any departments that haven't been allocated to a sheet
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Department " & deptNum & " has not been allocated to anyone!"
                End
        End Select
        With Worksheets(destSheet)
            'Work out which row to copy to
            destRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'destRow will be 2 if the sheet was currently empty, so adjust to be 1 instead
            If destRow = 2 Then destRow = 1
            'Copy everything from the end of the previous section to the end of this section
            Rows((prevRow + 1) & ":" & deptRow).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & destRow)
        End With
        'Set up for next section
        prevRow = deptRow
        deptRow = Range("A:A").FindNext(Cells(deptRow, "A")).Row
        'The loop will stop once the newly found "Department" is on a row before the last processed section
    Loop
End Sub
```